# Is CSS3 transitions in Chrome Browsers hardware accelerated in PCs?

Tags: google-chrome, css, transition

I have tested my website in MACs & PCs. I have found out that the CSS3 transitions runs more smoothly on MACs than PCs. Actually, my friend which have the latest gaming computer, I can see the frames lagging more frequently than my MacBook Air. Isn't CSS3 transitions hardware accelerated in PCs too?

Comment: Are GPU Accelerated Compositing and GPU Accelerated Canvas 2D enabled in chrome://flags ?

Answer (score 1):

I think Chrome only accelerates 3D transformations. You can trick it into accelerating 2D ones though by adding -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to the element.

More details are here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/#toc-hardware-accell

If you use jQuery there is a nice little plugin that tries to hardware accelerate/convert to transitions all animations here: http://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced